# Trying to stop a click function after the first use

Tags: jquery, function

I'm just starting out with jQuery and I've been stuck on this code for the better part of the night. I have 4 p tags that fade in/out when you click on them. First, you have to click the header to see the first paragraph, and then you click the first paragraph to get to the second, and so on... anyway, after the first click of the header, I want the click function on it to stop. I've tried everything I came across tonight, but came up short. Bare in mind that I'm rather new to this, so the answer might have been out there and I just didn't get it. Anyway, here is the code I have:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("p").hide();


    $("header").click(function(){
        $("#p1").fadeTo(1500,1);

     });<!--end of h1 click -->


    $("#p1").click(function(){
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").fadeTo(1000,1)
    });<!-- end of p1 click-->

    $("#p2").click(function(){
        $("#p2").hide();
        $("#p3").fadeTo(1000,1)
    });<!--end of p2 click-->

    $("#p3").click(function(){
        $("#p3").hide();
        $("#p4").fadeTo(1000,1);

    });<!--end of p3 click-->

    $("#p4").click(function(){
        $("#p4").hide();
    });<!--end of p4 click-->


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to register a handler which will get executed only once

```
$("header").one('click', function () {
    $("#p1").fadeTo(1500, 1);

}); <!--end of h1 click -->
```

Comment: Do you know how can we achieve event delegation with `.one()` .? A doubt raised after reading this question.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. One question I forgot to ask (I'm sorry, I'm rather new to this): I want to be able to have to code loop. What I mean is I want to be able to click the header again, after I click the  p4 selector.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to use click only once.

```
$("header").one(function(){
   $("#p1").fadeTo(1500,1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .one() is the best options but you can use this also :

```
$("header").on("click",function(){
   $("#p1").fadeTo(1500,1);
   $(this).off("click");
});
```

Comment: `.one()` in turns call the `.on()` function.   `one: function(types, selector, data, fn) {
      return this.on(types, selector, data, fn, 1);
    }`

Comment: `$("header").on("click",function(){
   $("#p1").fadeTo(1500,1);
},1); `